# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'; Defining and calling a recursive method

Tags: python, class, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a simple 'insert' method to my Tree class:

```
    class Tree:
      def __init__(self, value):
        self.node = value
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild  = None

      def insert(self, value):
        if self.node is None:
            self.node = value
            return True
        if self.node is not value:
            if self.node > value:
                if self.leftChild  is None:
                    self.leftChild  = value
                else:
                    return self.leftChild.insert(value)
            if self.node < value:
                if self.rightChild  is None:
                    self.rightChild  = value
                else:
                     return self.rightChild.insert(value)
        else:
            return False



tree = Tree(5)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(10)
```

The code above gives the following error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

The error arises at the line  'return self.rightChild.insert(value)' when insert method is called via tree.insert(10).

I have tried replacing the erroneous line by 'return insert(self.leftChild, value)', but that gives me the following error:

> NameError: global name 'insert' is not defined

I do not know how to fix this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the left and right children to be just `value`, which is an integer. To implement your recursive structure, you should set them to be new Tree objects; that way you can call on their Tree methods. It's an easy fix - just use `Tree(value)` instead of `value`.

```
    class Tree:
      def __init__(self, value):
        self.node = value
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild  = None

      def insert(self, value):
        if self.node is None:
            self.node = value
            return True
        if self.node is not value:
            if self.node > value:
                if self.leftChild  is None:
                    self.leftChild  = Tree(value)
                else:
                    return self.leftChild.insert(value)
            if self.node < value:
                if self.rightChild  is None:
                    self.rightChild  = Tree(value)
                else:
                     return self.rightChild.insert(value)
        else:
            return False



tree = Tree(5)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(10)
```

Comment: Thank you! My apologies if my question is quite basic, but then why do we not use <self.node = Tree(value)> while assigning value to the root node? We just just use <self.node = value>

Comment: Each Tree needs to know three things: its left child (which is a Tree), its right child (which is a Tree), and its value (which is just a number). These are what the three variable correspond to. If tree.node was a Tree, then that Tree would have a node which was a Tree, and that Tree would have a node which was a Tree, and we'd have infinite descent and wouldn't actually store the value anywhere. It might be clearer if you rename self.node to self.value to remind yourself that it's a number.

Comment: Think of it as a tree diagram: self.node is the number in the little circle, and self.leftChild and self.rightChild are the arrows to left and right.

Comment: You have saved the day!! Awesome explanation! Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)